# I want to add "CC" and Text in the body of this code. What should I do to add it?

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I have been able to create an automated email reply as I wanted. However, I wanted to add text in the body of the email and cc to add email address. How should I add it?

```
Sub FwdSelToAddr()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objFwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strAddr As String
    Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objReply As MailItem
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        strAddr = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.Body, "Email:")
        If strAddr <> "" Then
            Set objFwd = objItem.Forward
            objFwd.To = strAddr
            objFwd.Display
        Else
            MsgBox "Could not extract address from message."
        End If
    End If
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objFwd = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is what I have done so far. I just want to be able to add CC email address and text in the body in the automated reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the code a bit by setting the `Cc` property and the `HTMLBody` one if you need to modify or update the message body:

```
If strAddr <> "" Then
  Set objFwd = objItem.Forward
  objFwd.To = strAddr
  objFwd.Cc = "email@address.com"
  objFwd.HTMLBody = "<b>Hello world</b>"
  objFwd.Display
Else
```

Be aware, to preserve the message body from the original email you need to insert your content between the opening `<body>` and closing `</body>` tags. If you need to add in the beginning of the message paste your additional text right after the opening tag, if you intend to paste it in the end of message - paste right before the closing tag.

Also you may find the `Recipients` property of the `MailItem` class helpful. It allows a more convenient way for setting up recipients for the Outlook items. You can read more about that property in the article that I wrote for the technical blog - [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Comment: I want to keep this information in the email reply. Does this particular code create a new email instead of keeping the original one?

Comment: Yes, the `Forward` method executes the `Forward` action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a `MailItem` object.

Comment: Is there a way I can include the original email beneath the forward action email? For example, when I run my code which is in the question above, it gives me a an email linking the trail to the original email.

Comment: When you call the `Forward` method the new email (forward) with an original body is returned back. You can paste your content right after the `<body>` tag to preserve the original below. The action is similar to forwarding email manually.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, is it possible for you to show it to me visually with an edited code because I am not able to understand.

Comment: The sample code is shown in the post.